# Заполнение двумерного массива через функцию в СИ

Tags: c, массивы, указатели

Нужно заполнить двумерный массив из 6 строк и 8 столбцов значениями от -5 до 15 через отдельную функцию в СИ.
Пробовал:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


void fillArr ( int** Arr )
{
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<8; j++)
        {
            Arr[i][j]=(rand()%21)-5;
        }
    }
}


void main ( void )
{
    int Arr[6][8];
    fillArr(Arr);
}
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
rk2.c: In function ‘main’:
rk2.c:21:13: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fillArr’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   21 |     fillArr(Arr);
      |             ^~~
      |             |
      |             int (*)[8]
rk2.c:5:22: note: expected ‘int **’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)[8]’
    5 | void fillArr ( int** Arr )
      |                ~~~~~~^~~
```

Вообще не понимаю ничего в указателях. Приведите пожалуйста пример.

Comment: Текст ошибки вы по принципиальным соображениям сообщать не хотите?

Comment: http://scrutator.me/post/2015/11/26/pointers_demystified_p1.aspx

Comment: Сразу исправьте i<=6 -> i<6. j<=8 -> j<8

Comment: Запишите `void fillArr ( int** Arr )` как `void fillArr ( int Arr[][8])`...

Answer (score 1):

Вариант реализации на "C":

```
void fillArr ( int* Arr, int rows, int columns )
{
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<columns; j++)
        {
            Arr[i*columns+j]=(rand()%21)-5;
        }
    }
}

void printArr ( int* Arr, int rows, int columns )
{
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<columns; j++)
        {
            printf("%6d ", Arr[i*columns+j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
void main (void)
{
    int Arr[6][8];
    fillArr(&Arr[0][0], 6, 8);
    printArr(&Arr[0][0], 6, 8); 
}

15      3      8     14     12     11      7     -5
14     15      9      0      8      1      2      3
 8      9     13     13      4      4     12      1
14      8      7      0     15      3      3      7
 3      4     -5     -1      0      2     -1     -2
12     13      6      4      7     -3     -5     -1
```